# Copy file from remote to local with Windows 10 Bash

Tags: bash, ssh, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to copy some files on a remote host to my local machine using Win 10 Bash Shell, due to security policies I can only do so from the remote, so I made sure local port is open, logged on to remote, and typed:

```
scp somefile johndoe@my.ip.address:~/
```

and I was prompted for password:

```
johndoe@my.ip.address's password:
```

which I don't have since I didn't setup any. Tried remote user's password, `johndoe`'s user password (setup by logging in as `johndoe` and simply running `passwd`) and the Windows 10 password, none worked. Then I tried to supply a root password, since I don't have one already I ran

```
sudo passwd root
```

and was told that `password updated successfully`. However the next time I run the same command it simply asked for new UNIX password as if none exists. Also `scp` still won't work with this password. Now I am stuck...

Comment: You need to give the password of `johndoe` on the machcine `my.ip.address`.

Comment: @terdon: is it the one setup by `passwd`? Tried but doesn't work

Comment: No, your `sudo passwd root` command sets root's password, you want johndoe's. Have you tried logging in as johndoe and simply running `passwd`?

Comment: @terdon: Yes, in fact that's the first thing I tired.

Comment: Then please [edit] your question and tell us so.

Comment: @terdon: that what meant by "`johndoe`'s local password", edited to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `scp` was trying to connect to Windows 10 system directly, instead of the Linux subsystem; and that's why none of the passwords works, since user `johndoe` doesn't exist on my Windows system in the first place.

To resolve the issue, I installed [OpenSSH for Windows](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases/). Then, instead of the Linux subsystem user name, I supplied my Windows user name (the one you get from typing `whoami` in Windows PowerShell or Command Prompt) to the command; `scp` still doesn't quite work (gave me `lost connection` error), but at least `sftp` does now:

```
sftp windows.user.name@my.ip.address
```